Constrained callback arguments
I have this:
const any = (any?: any): any => any;

export type Fn = (cb: (...args: (string | number)[]) => any) => any;

const Fn: Fn = any();

const t1 = Fn((x: unknown) => x); // Allowed
const t2 = Fn(<X>(x: X) => x); // Allowed

How can i disallow unknown parameters inside the callback?
I have tried:

Setting strictFunctionTypes inside tsconfig.json
Using an Exact utility type
Using a generic on the cb declaration

None of these have worked for me so far.
So, how do I avoid callbacks without constrained arguments.
Here is what should be allowed:
const t3 = Fn((a: string, b: number) => {});
const t4 = Fn(() => {});
const t5 = Fn((x: string | number, y: string) => {});
const t6 = Fn(<X extends number>(x: X) => x);
const t7 = Fn(<X extends string, Y extends string>(x: X, y: Y) => x + y);

Currently most of these don't work either...
How can I solve this issue?
Playground

Can you demonstrate why you want this? You're pushing back against the type system, which is the way it is for a reason. If a function accepts unknown then it should be fine to use it as a function that accepts string | number. That's just contravariance. Why do you care that a function is more versatile than you need? Without a use case this seems like an XY problem, for surely you have some actual thing you're trying to do and fighting against contravariance seems like a good solution to you. What is the use case? There might well be a more appropriate solution.

Here is my usecase.
I have already tried to make it simpler, but I hope it gives an idea.
Basically, I give the callback, and after provide the argument types for validation.
Since I can only validate custom types, I need to constrain all callbacks to have only custom type arguments. Does that make sense? I don't want to declare that a callback must be of type x, but that all callbacks contain only custom type arguments.

I'm confused about the use case and how the example code in the question relates to it. It doesn't make sense for you to care if a callback function accepts more things than your custom types, since there's no principled way to validate a callback other than calling it, and if it accepts your custom types, who cares if it also accepts other things? It's like saying you want a veterinarian that only accepts dogs. Why do you care if the vet also knows how to treat cats? Isn't "treats at least dogs" enough? If you can express your use case as a [mre] in the question that might help?

(see prev comment) I mean, you can fight against the type system as shown in this playground link, but it's really not warranted unless you can demonstrate a clear use case where things go wrong if you don't do this. I can write an answer with this suggestion, but it will be full of caveats. How would you like to proceed?

The usecase is exactly the same as my question, therefor the original question is the minimal reproducible example. See how it works if I don't constrain the params: link. Or if i set the argument constraint to any: link.
Your playground link is broken, and leads me to the url-shorten website.
I am not sure if we talk about the same thing. I dont care what happens in the callback. I care that the developer declares a function that is "valid". If an argument is unknown, in my "type system" it would be a non-existent type.

(see prev comment) Since everything should be strongly typed (not in TS but in the system), a function without constraint is equivilant to an "any" type.

To clarify: The callback must remain within the bounds of my system. Each callback is declared individually and serves its own specific purpose.

I don’t know what to say about the broken playground link. I’m on mobile right now but I’ll check again when I get to my real computer and provide a new link. Still not convinced that your use case is a good enough reason to fight against contravariance of function parameters, but again, I’m on mobile now so I can’t be sure yet. Might be a while but I’ll check as soon as I can.

• Oh goodness, my link was wrong, sorry! The correct link is this one. Does that behave how you want? • I understand that you want a particular behavior, but could you show something that actually goes wrong? Like something unsafe that's allowed if you don't prohibit "invalid" callbacks? If there's some soundness issue, I'd like to see it. The links you provided show things you don't like being accepted, but does that lead to problems at runtime? And if so, can you demonstrate that?

No problem at all! I do appreciate your patience. I see you do understand exactly what I want, since your solution does what I need. But clearly, you don't see why I want it. I try to explain it here . If that doesn't explain it, I might be very bad at expressing my thoughts. Anyways, if it's still unclear thats fine, it does exactly what I want, and I believe to know what I want. Thanks for your time and solution. If you want to answer it, I would happily accept it.

Okay I've written an answer with my caveats about type safety. I think I do now understand what you're trying to do, and it's like you want TS to act as a linter to enforce a non-type-safety-related constraint.

TypeScript really isn't intended to help enforce constraints like this. It allows you to assign a value of type (x: X) => void to a variable of type (y: Y) => void whenever Y extends X, because if a function accepts all X values, then of course it will also accept Y values, because Y extends X.  It's a natural consequence of the contravariance of function types in their parameter types; see Difference between Variance, Covariance, Contravariance, Bivariance and Invariance in TypeScript.
It sounds like you want TypeScript to act as a linter for your code base, preventing developers from mentioning types you don't like in certain places.
To say that you want to prevent passing in an argument of type (x: unknown) => void to a parameter of type (x: string | number) => void is to fight against the TypeScript type system.  Such a restriction is not a matter of type safety, because it doesn't seem to have anything to do with avoiding runtime errors due to type mismatches. You can certainly fight the TypeScript type system, but any solution inside TypeScript is going to be complicated and probably fragile.
Here's one possible approach:
export type Fn = <T extends Function>(
    cb: T extends (T extends (...args: infer A) => void ?
        A[number] extends (string | number) ? unknown : never
        : never) ? T : never
) => any;

Now Fn is generic in the type F of the cb parameter. When you call Fn(cb), TypeScript will infer T to be the type of cb, and then it will check it against the complicated conditional type above. If it matches T extends (...args: infer A) => void ? A[number] extends (string | number) ? unknown : never : never then the parameter type evaluates to T, and since T extends T then it is acceptable. Otherwise it evaluates to never, and since T extends never cannot be true for any actual cb you pass in, then it is unacceptable.
So what's T extends (...args: infer A) => void ? A[number] extends (string | number) ? unknown : never : never?  Well, we're using conditional type inference to extract the tuple type of T's parameters into the type parameter A, and then checking if the union of the element types of A (that is, A[number]) is assignable to string | number. If it is, then we know that all the parameters of T are subtypes of string | number, and the overall type evaluates to unknown. If not, then at least one parameter of T is not a subtype of string | number, and the overall type evaluates to never.  So that means if the parameters are what you want, the type of the cb parameter is T extends unknown ? T : never, or just T, which accepts the argument you passed in. And if any parameter isn't want you want, the type of the cb parameter is T extends never ? T : never, or just never, which rejects the argument you passed in.
I did say it was complicated.
Let's test it out:
const t1 = Fn((x: unknown) => x); // disallowed
const t2 = Fn(<X,>(x: X) => x); // disallowed
Fn((x: boolean) => x); // disallowed
Fn((x: string | boolean) => x); // disallowed

const t3 = Fn((a: string, b: number) => { });
const t4 = Fn(() => { });
const t5 = Fn((x: string | number, y: string) => { });
const t6 = Fn(<X extends number>(x: X) => x);
const t7 = Fn(<X extends string, Y extends string>(x: X, y: Y) => x + y);

This is all behaving as you desired. The first four calls above are rejected, since the callbacks' parameter types involve types outside the string or number range... even though for t1 and t2, there would almost certainly be no runtime errors caused by it. The next five calls are all accepted, since the callbacks' parameter types are all within the string and number range.
Playground link to code

Great answer - exactly what I was looking for. I believe to understand why you think it's not appropriate, but for me TypeScript is a tool to offload congnitive load to a tool, and not have to worry about stuff all the time. I guess I am not a purist, in that case. Rules are meant to be broken :). I tried it out and it seems fairly stable. Thanks for your time and the in-depth response!

It really truly depends on what you're doing at runtime whether or not you have to "worry about stuff". TS fundamentally allows assignments you're trying to prohibit, so all you need to do to circumvent the restriction is to do such an assignment before passing it to your Fn function, as shown in this playground link.  Does that matter? If not, great. If so, oh well, you're looking for a linter and not TypeScript.

I see. Well in this case Fn is specifically designed for functions to be declared inside.
Apart from that all calls would be validated anyways, so issues would become apparent fairly quickly. if not on the type level then in testing. I get the point, but I believe it's hard to have 100% type safety in TS anyways, as it's not truly strongly typed? That aside, I do appreciate you pointing out the flaws of the approach. I'd take this over having no "safety checks". Sure, a linter works fine for me - though, isn't it written in TypeScript? So, technically, a TS-linter?

• Even if TS were 100% type safe, the thing I'm showing you would still be allowed. Function parameter contravariance is 100% type safe, it's the desired behavior for all sound type systems. Allowing (x: unknown) => void to be assignable to (x: string) => void is a feature of type safety, not a violation of it.  The kind of "safety" you're trying to achieve here is something else entirely, a non-soundness-related invariant for types, and it's probably best to use a different term for it, so as not to digress about type safety when you discuss it. • Not sure what you mean about "TS-linter"

Well by 100% typesafe I mean that there would be no "any" or "unknown" types either. What I am trying to build, is a type-system on top of TS. It has only unique types. No "sub" or "super" types. Type x is only assingable to type y through coersion at runtime or on the type level. Even Int could only be assigned to Num through coersion.

I will face this issue as long as any and unknown exist in TS. So I believe there is no contravarience in what I am trying to build. I just want to pretend any and unknown don't exist at all. "Ts-linter" was supposed to be funny. Well to me a linter is an external tool. since this isn't and it's not TS either, what is it? How do you want to call it?

• unknown is type safe. If you're using the word "typesafe" to exclude unknown, or supertypes, or subtypes, then you're using the word in an unconventional way and all it will do is confuse people. Please, use different terminology, or you will go round and round in circles when trying to discuss what you're doing. • I'm saying you need an external tool to actually prohibit something like unknown. TS won't do it for you, you need a linter. You could probably write a custom rule for typescript-eslint that gets you much closer to your goal than the thing I wrote in this answer.

Sure, I doubt linters are versatile enough to conditionally apply those rules. I mean, I can’t entirely avoid using any or unknown - I have to build the library on top of something, after all. I will do my research. I am still happy with this. Thanks!
